# React Testing Library - Lazy Loading - Error act()

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, automated-tests, react-testing-library, testing-library

I have the following simple test file for the  component. I based the test on this React documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/test-utils.html#act

```js
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';
import App from './App'
import { screen } from '@testing-library/react'

let container: HTMLElement;

beforeEach(() => {
  container = document.createElement('div');
  document.body.appendChild(container);
});

it('can render and update a counter', () => {
  act(() => {
    ReactDOM.createRoot(container).render(<App />);
  });
  const title = screen.getByText('My App');
  expect(title).toBeInTheDocument()
});
```

The test does pass, but I always receive an annoying error:

```
  Warning: A suspended resource finished loading inside a test, but the event was not wrapped in act(...).
  
  When testing, code that resolves suspended data should be wrapped into act(...):
  
  act(() => {
    /* finish loading suspended data */
  });
  /* assert on the output */
  
  This ensures that you're testing the behavior the user would see in the browser. Learn more at https://reactjs.org/link/wrap-tests-with-act
```

When I remove from the  a component which uses react lazy loading the error message goes away. **So how can I test over React Lazy Loading without this kind of issue for React 18?**

Here is my `setupTest.ts`

```js
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
```

Here is my `package.json` dependencies

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@react-spring/web": "^9.4.5",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5"
 },
"devDependencies": {
    "@react-spring/types": "^9.4.5",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.2.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.9",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.5",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.25",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.36.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.36.1",
    "eslint": "^8.23.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^3.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.31.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.6.4"
  }
```

I already tried several solutions like using `await waitFor(...)`, `findBy(...)`, removing the act method from the test file, but no success yet.

I'm using Node 16.16

Answer (score 1):

I just resolved it by inserting this lines at the end of the test:

```js
await screen.findByText('some text');
```

I understood that since changes occurs after the initial render, we need to "tell" the Testing Library that it does and to wait for it. It does not need the `act()` wrapping the render method then.

Answer (score -1):

did you try putting your

```
const title = screen.getByText('My App');
```

line of code inside act(){...}?

Comment: Yes I just tried and this way even the test fails